# How to use @Inject in spring boot while using gradle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I am new to Java so this might be a silly question.

I am trying to use @Inject in a class (We are using spring boot and for jars we are using gradle file.)

When I am trying to use @Inject, it throws an error saying **Inject cannot be resolved to a type.**

Do I need to add anything in my gradle file in order to use @Inject?

Please help!

Comment: can you give us an example. above error occur i guess when the line where you are using this @Inject annotation is not valid.

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to use `@Inject` over `@Autowired`? To use `@Inject` you need an additional dependency for `javax.inject`.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. Adding additional dependency of javax.inject worked. Actually we wanted to read request body in exception handler. Hence was trying to use inject.

Comment: Why would you need `@Inject` for that? Just use an `@RequestBody String body` if you want the raw data, no need for an `@Inject`. Seems like over engineering.